# How can I create a python Kivy gui that can interact with my python console chat bot using kivy labels

Tags: python, kivy, console-application, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I create a python Kivy gui that can interact with my python console chat bot using kivy labels?

This is part of the code for the chat bot in the console

```
while True:
  
    query = input("Dimensional Entity Input> ")
    query = [(w) for w in (query.split())]
    question = " ".join(query)
    response = k.respond(question)
    if response:
        print("Gestú > ", response)
```

This is the code for the python kivy

```
class MyLayout(Widget):
        def press(self):
         self.ids.name_label.text = f' {response}'

         self.ids.name_input.text = ''

class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

This is the code for the .kv

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
    
        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: ""
            font_size: 32

        TextInput:
            id: name_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (1, .5)

        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.press()
```

I have tried every way I can think of but I can only get the kivy app to display one response from my console based bot and the button won’t work a second time. Please help me if you can!!??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a chat bot that prints to the console and you can respond through the console to the bot. I want to know if there is a way to make a kivy gui I can use as an interface to communicate with the bot that’s already running in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you know kivy then you only need to embed your functions for both user and AI in buttons, textinputs and labels or prompts.
Meaning, create complete UI, then write the appropriate functions (the code wrote to make AI do ...) for AI or user interaction in the widgets.
So that if you type a sentence in a text area, that event can be invoked by a button click, sent to the AI . And create a label to view its response.
msg me if unclear.